# How do the Power Rangers: Megaforce defend Earth?

Tags: power-rangers, power-rangers-megaforce

In Power Rangers: Megaforce, the world is under siege by an Alien Armada. The Aliens launch multiple assaults on Earth and the Power Rangers were all that stood between them and conquest every time. So how do five people who live in the same city and seemingly never travel, defend the entire Earth? I understand that Power Rangers is a kids show and this may have never been addressed, but is there and in universe answer?

Comment: Very well, thank you.

Comment: I must admit, I did not expect to come into work today and read about Power Rangers.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg I didn't expect to come into work yesterday and answer a question about Power Rangers.

Comment: @Thunderforge: Wikipedia tells me that Megaforce is the 20th season of Power Rangers, not its own series. I was going to write a tag wiki excerpt for [tag:power-rangers-megaforce], but I'm not sure what distinguishes it from [tag:power-rangers]. Then there's Super Megaforce, which is the 21st season. Or was it a reboot, distinct from other Power Rangers seasons?

Comment: @amarillo Think of Power Rangers the same as you would think of a movie series like James Bond. Each series/movie is self-contained, and has little to do with other series, yet is still linked because they use the same basic character premise (in Power Rangers, there are different teens becoming rangers using a different theme and power source). In recent years, Power Rangers has done two-season blocks with the same team of Rangers (the second of which has "super" in their name) like how recent Bond movies have connections. So Power Rangers is to (Super) Megaforce as James Bond is to Goldenye.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Megaforce may do the best job explaining this. Gosei is a very powerful wizard with advanced technology; he is able to teleport the rangers to multiple locations fairly easily and often. Early transportation frameworks seen in previous shows, for example Mighty Morphing, were mainly *Home City -> Base* and *Base -> Home City* (exceptions exist).

Later on in the series in Super Megaforce, they get flight vehicles like the *Super Mega Skyship* and the *Legendary Megazord* that travel amazingly fast. When searching for Turtle Island to get the Red Lion Wildzord, they circumnavigate the planet many times in a short period of time.

Throughout most of the series though the home city is the primary focus. The villains often explain or allude to the reason why they attack the heroes' home city: the Megaforce Rangers are the largest threat to the conquest of Earth.

**Edit:**

To clarify that last point, why the enemy focuses on the rangers, it is important to differentiate between Megaforce (Season 1) and Super Megaforce (Season 2).

In Megaforce, the primary antagonists have one ship: the Warstar. And for reasons I won't go into, generally there is only one *Monster of the Week*. It is irrelevant whether the villains attack the home city or not (sometimes they do, sometimes they don't) since the rangers can teleport.

In Super Megaforce, the primary antagonist is the Armada. At the beginning of the season the villains do send forth a global assault. The shiny new *Legendary Megazord* repels the attack, severely damaging the advance fleet. From that point on, the enemies know that it is throwing away resources to do a mass attack. The Legendary Megazord will just glass the fleet again if they do. From that point on, it is wise to send elite troops (commanders or higher) to eliminate the power rangers so that the fleet may swoop in and conquer.

Comment: Reading this answer I was struck by how incredibly *ridiculous* the names in Power Rangers are/were - "Super Mega Skyship", "Legendary Megazord", "Red Lion Wildzord". Sounds a bit like someone had a bit too much THC.

Comment: They constantly attack the heroes' home city because the Rangers are the largest threat to the conquest of Earth -> That means that they constantly attack the one place where the Rangers are most often, simply because the Rangers are there. Because the Rangers are there, the enemies inevitably (SPOILER ALERT) get defeated. The Rangers are the largest threat because they're the largest threat.

Comment: @Jake may I refer you to a [tautology club](https://xkcd.com/703/) membership?

Comment: @Jake Yeah, the enemies are low on the IQ scale. They could just go to the polar opposite of the world, destroy a city. Run away. Rinse and repeat until only the heroes' home city and the neighbouring towns are the only places not on fire.

Comment: @Lan - But usually it's the appearance of the Enemy which causes the Rangers to form and be empowered.  If they attacked a different city, they could presumably cause the formation of another Ranger team.  And Rangers seem immune to the [Conservation of Ninjitsu](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ConservationOfNinjutsu) rule.

Answer (score 5):

From memory most Power Rangers series have something that the villain needs before their big invasion or they live in a location villain needs or sometimes just a personal grudge against the Power Rangers is all that keeps them coming back.

Comment: Have you ever been to Auckland...

Comment: Actually yes I have. I think the significance of Auckland is part of the fantasy of the show :P

Comment: Commence Invasion!

Comment: Vote up just for your username, hahahha! But agree'd they do just seem to hate the rangers for no real reason, at least initially. Then obviously you have the entire seasons of foiled plans.